# range between interval in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

Good day,
Give me  advice,please,
How can i replace this Oracle syntax:

```sql
sum(fact) over(partition by name order by rep_date range between interval '20' month preceding and current row) as w_sum
```

to use it in Hive? I have a mistake related with interval '20'

Comment: could you provide an example of input and output and what the statement meabs pls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the rep_date into seconds since Unix epoch using unix_timestamp and then calculate the seconds for 20 months and use it in the range,between. Hive does not support specifying interval type in range.

```
sum(fact) over(
    partition by name 
    order by unix_timestamp(rep_date,'MM-dd-yyyy') -- Specify the rep_date format here
    range between 51840000 preceding and current row) as w_sum
```

Comment: Are u sure that it will work correctly? What about that different months have different amount of days in month? So i think we can get different amount of seconds depends on what months in this 20 months?