# HIVE - compute statistics over partitions with window based on date

Tags: sql, datetime, hive, window-functions, date-arithmetic

I've seen solutions for problems similar to mine, but none quite work for me. Also I'm confident that there should be a way to make it work.

Given a table with

| ID | Date | target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 1 |
| 1 | 2020-01-02 | 1 |
| 1 | 2020-01-03 | 0 |
| 1 | 2020-01-04 | 1 |
| 1 | 2020-01-04 | 0 |
| 1 | 2020-06-01 | 1 |
| 1 | 2020-06-02 | 1 |
| 1 | 2020-06-03 | 0 |
| 1 | 2020-06-04 | 1 |
| 1 | 2020-06-04 | 0 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 1 |

ID is BIGINT, target is Int and Date is DATE

I want to compute, for each ID/Date, the sum and the number of rows for the same ID in the 3 months and 12 months before the Date (inclusive). Example of output:

| ID | Date | Sum_3 | Count_3 | Sum_12 | Count_12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2020-01-02 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2020-01-03 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2020-01-04 | 3 | 5 | 3 | 5 |
| 1 | 2020-06-01 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 6 |
| 1 | 2020-06-02 | 2 | 2 | 5 | 7 |
| 1 | 2020-06-03 | 2 | 3 | 6 | 8 |
| 1 | 2020-06-04 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 10 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

How can I get this time of results in HIVE?
I'm not sure if I should use analytical functions (and how), group by, etc...?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [range between interval in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52992405/range-between-interval-in-hive)

Comment: That answer has the issue pointed on the comments to the answer - but I will analyse it, thanks - also, it does not consider the count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can do an estimation of interval (1 month = 30 days): (an improvement of GMB's answer)

```
with t as (
    select ID, Date,
        sum(target) target,
        count(target) c_target
    from table
    group by ID, Date
)
select ID, Date,
    sum(target) over(
        partition by ID
        order by unix_timestamp(Date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
        range 60 * 60 * 24 * 90 preceding
    ) sum_3,
    sum(c_target) over(
        partition by ID
        order by unix_timestamp(Date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
        range 60 * 60 * 24 * 90 preceding
    ) count_3,
    sum(target) over(
        partition by ID
        order by unix_timestamp(Date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
        range 60 * 60 * 24 * 360 preceding
    ) sum_12,
    sum(c_target) over(
        partition by ID
        order by unix_timestamp(Date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
        range 60 * 60 * 24 * 360 preceding
    ) count_12
from t
```

Or if you want exact intervals, you can do self joins (but expensive):

```
with t as (
    select ID, Date,
        sum(target) target,
        count(target) c_target
    from table
    group by ID, Date
)
select
    t_3month.ID, 
    t_3month.Date, 
    t_3month.sum_3, 
    t_3month.count_3, 
    sum(t3.target) sum_12, 
    sum(t3.c_target) count_12
from (
    select 
        t1.ID, 
        t1.Date,
        sum(t2.target) sum_3,
        sum(t2.c_target) count_3
    from t t1
    left join t t2
    on t2.Date > t1.Date - interval 3 month and
       t2.Date <= t1.Date and
       t1.ID = t2.ID
    group by t1.ID, t1.Date
) t_3month
left join t t3
on t3.Date > t_3month.Date - interval 12 month and
   t3.Date <= t_3month.Date and
   t_3month.ID = t3.ID
group by t_3month.ID, t_3month.Date, t_3month.sum_3, t_3month.count_3
order by ID, Date;
```

Comment: Thanks - I did try something similar, but the gigantic size of the join result prevented the query from finishing (and btw, I thought the in Hive join conditions had to be = and not > or <= )

Comment: @DiogoSantos I edited my answer to provide another perhaps more efficient method (mostly inspired by GMB). see if that helps?

Comment: I will test both answers (your's and GMB's updated version), but both look like they will solve the issue. I'm curious to see if there is any performance diference, however.

Comment: btw, what if I want to exclude the last 2 days relative to each row - ex: my output line 4 becomes 2 | 2 ?

Comment: @DiogoSantos then you can use `range bewteen 60 * 60 * 24 * 90 preceding and 60 * 60 * 24 * 2 preceding`

Answer (score 2):

If you can live with an approximation of months as a number of days, then you can use window functions in Hive:

```
select id, date, 
    count(*) over(
        partition by id 
        order by unix_timestamp(date)
        range 60 * 60 * 24 * 90 preceding -- 90 days
    ) as count_3,
    sum(target) over(
        partition by id 
        order by unix_timestamp(date)
        range 60 * 60 * 24 * 90 preceding
    ) as sum_3,
    count(*) over(
        partition by id 
        order by unix_timestamp(date)
        range 60 * 60 * 24 * 360 preceding -- 360 days
    ) as count_12,
    sum(target) over(
        partition by id 
        order by unix_timestamp(date)
        range 60 * 60 * 24 * 360 preceding
    ) as sum_12
from mytable
```

You can aggregate in the same query:

```
select id, date, 
    sum(count(*)) over(
        partition by id 
        order by unix_timestamp(date)
        range 60 * 60 * 24 * 90 preceding -- 90 days
    ) as count_3,
    sum(sum(target)) over(
        partition by id 
        order by unix_timestamp(date)
        range 60 * 60 * 24 * 90 preceding
    ) as sum_3,
    sum(count(*)) over(
        partition by id 
        order by unix_timestamp(date)
        range 60 * 60 * 24 * 360 preceding -- 360 days
    ) as count_12,
    sum(sum(target)) over(
        partition by id 
        order by unix_timestamp(date)
        range 60 * 60 * 24 * 360 preceding
    ) as sum_12
from mytable
group by id, date, unix_timestamp(date)
```

Comment: the dates are duplicated in the source table, but are deduplicated in the results table... so this query doesn't give the expected results

Comment: @mck: ah ok, I did not notice that when I first answered. I added another query to aggregate as needed.

Comment: @GMB any reason to group by unix_timestamp(date) on top of date?

Comment: @DiogoSantos: that's because the `unix_timestamp()` expression appears in the `order by` clauses of the window function. I don't know if Hive will figure out that this is functionally dependent on `date`, so I took the safe path. You can try and run the query without the `unix_timestamp()` in the `group by` clause and see if you get a compilation error (I don't have a Hive database at hand to test).